# grails delete not persistent

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I was trying to delete a more complex related object from my db, so I investigated using grails console and came up with this:

```
            TextContent textContent = ...The item to delete...

            // TextContent hasMany BundleText
            // BundleText belongsTo BundleVersion
            textContent.bundleTexts.each {
                BundleVersion bundleVersion = it.bundleVersion
                bundleVersion.removeFromBundleTexts(it)
                textContent.removeFromBundleTexts(it)
                it.delete()
                //bundleVersion.save()
            }
            // Language hasMany TextContent
            // Language belongsTo textContent (?)
            textContent.language.removeFromTextContents(textContent)

            // TextContent belongsTo textCode
            TextCode textCode = textContent.textCode
            textCode.removeFromTextContents(textContent)

            textContent.delete()
            //textCode.save()
```

Now this all works fine in the grails console, so I put it inside my database service, and run the app.
The app runs the method succesfully (verified), but when it re-read the collection it comes up again.. 
Big mystery...!?

Anyone seen anything like it? Or am I just embarassingly naive?

**EDIT**

For clarification:

```
class TextCode {
    static hasMany = [ textContents : TextContent ]
}

class TextContent {
    Language language
    static belongsTo = [ textCode : TextCode ]
    static hasMany = [ bundleTexts : BundleText]
}

class BundleText {
  TextContent textContent
  static belongsTo = [ bundleVersion : BundleVersion ]
}

class Language {
    static hasMany = [ textContents : TextContent ]
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your domains TextCode, TextContent, and BundleVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the above didn't work, but I managed to solve it by direct HQL instead.

```
BundleText.executeUpdate("delete BundleText bt where bt.textContent=:content", [content: textContent])
TextContent.executeUpdate("delete TextContent tc where tc.id = :id", [id: textContent.id])
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried flush:true which direct the GORM to persist the changes back to the database.like this one ..

```
def book = Book.get(1)
book.delete(flush: true)
```

flush:true is all the trick you need , or you should modify the config  of datasource.groovy on a section

```
dbCreate
```

and say it like

```
dbUpdate
```

Comment: Yes, it flush it without any problems. It works and persists it fine when using the console. It "works" in the app, except the delete is not persisted..

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen i didn't get your idea about it works in console or you mean(GroovyConsole) ?

Comment: run 'grails console' and you get the interactive console with the grails app preloaded..